# MS Access SQL to Update a RecordSet in Table/Query

Tags: sql, sql-update, where-clause, dao, recordset

I need help regarding the `WHERE` clause of an `SQL` statement to **UPDATE** field values [olnAg] in a query (***qryCLFull*** same as ***tblCLFull***). The field [**olnAg**] should be updated to the second text of [**cellLine**] field. So for example if [cellLine] has "

> This is the cellLine field

[olnAg] should have

> is

Getting the recordset and values has been successful with the code below (with the click of a button on `frmSecWord` but the issue with UPDATE of the [olnAg] field.

```
Private Sub btnBySpace_Click() 
    Dim rsON As DAO.Recordset 
    Dim rsNN As DAO.Recordset 
    Dim db2 As Database 
    Dim sqlON As String 
    Dim sqlNN As String 
     
    Dim newVal As String 
    Dim arr As Variant 
 
    sqlON = " SELECT  cellLine FROM  qryCLFull" 
    sqlNN = " SELECT  olnAg FROM  qryCLFull" 
 
    Set db2 = CurrentDb 
     
    Set rsON = db2.OpenRecordset(sqlON)  
    Set rsNN = db2.OpenRecordset(sqlNN) 
    arr = Split(rsON!cellline, " ") 
     
    If IsNull(arr(1)) Then 
    newVal = arr(0) 
    Else: newVal = arr(1) 
    End If 
 
    Do Until rsON.EOF 
    If Not IsNull(rsON.Fields(0).Value) Then 
 
    sqlstr = "UPDATE qryCLFull SET qryCLFull.olnAg = '" & newVal & "' 
    db2.Execute sqlstr 
    End If 
     
    rsON.MoveNext 
    rsNN.MoveNext 
   
    Loop 
 
    rsON.Close 
    rsNN.Close 
     
    Set rsNN = Nothing 
    Set rsNN = Nothing 
    Set db2 = Nothing 
     
End Sub
```

[image]

Now with this UPDATE and SQL code, all the records of [***olNAg***] are changed to "***is***" instead of records WHERE [CellLine] has the text "***This is the cellLine field***" I have tried severally to adjust the `WHERE` clause but I haven't been able to write a correct clause. This sql updates [olnAg] for all records in the table instead of just for instances where we find that particular rsON!CellLine.  Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show sample data to see more examples of `newVal`? Can it ever contain a single quote? Try to `Debug.Print newVal` to output in Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) just before the update to see which value it errs on.

Comment: Hello @Parfait. Everything works well. My problem is getting the UPDATE (on olnAg) WHERE [CellLine] = rsON.Fields(0).Value. **I do not know how to combine the strings and the ```sql``` with the ```WHERE``` clause**.  I'm now typing from my Mac and do not have MS Access so I cannot share the debug prints. The error will be the as it is more of semantics issue than syntax. .

Comment: Without tabular data to illustrate (current input / desired output) I am having trouble understanding your issue. Where are you attempts at the `WHERE` clause?